# Play With Numbers Programming Challenge (mean value of subarrays)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve this [Play with Numbers](https://www.hackerearth.com/ja/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/play-with-numbers-2/) problem in Hackerearth. I have passed the test cases but, I kept getting time limit exceeded. Can someone help me improve its performance in order to pass the time limit, please?

This is my code -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, q, i, l, r, j, sum;
    cin >> n >> q;
    int *arr = new int[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        cin >> l >> r;
        for (j = l - 1; j <= r - 1; j++)
        {
            sum += arr[j];
        }
        cout << sum / (r - l + 1) << endl;
    }
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: Right now you are solving the problem every subarray sequentially.
Consider what happens when subarrays overlap: you are walking the same elements multiple times. You should rewrite your program to walk the array only once but keep track of multiple subarrays at the same time. So, as a rough outline: 1) sort all subarrays by their start element; 2) for every element, see if you are starting a new subarray or ending an existing one, and update existing tracked arrays.

Comment: Fast I/O is one clue. There are a couple of unbinding tricks you can do to stdin that will make it slightly faster for large inputs.

Comment: You don't need fast I/O here. You have to remove the inner loop. Instead of storing the elements in the array, store the cumulative sum, e. g. 1, 2 ,2, 1, 4 -> 1, 3, 5, 6, 10. Then you can calculate the sum of subarray with last_element - first_element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the inner loop. Instead of storing the elements in the array, store the cumulative sum.

E. g. the elements are 1, 2 ,2, 1, 4.
You have to store 1, (1 + 2 =) 3, (1 + 2 + 2 =) 5, (1 + 2 + 2 + 1 =)6, (1 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 4 =) 10. Then you can calculate the sum of subarray with last_element - first_element.

E. g. for start index 2 and end index = 5 you get 2 + 2 + 1 + 4 = 10 - 1.
You don't need the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. This trick will also be useful for me in solving new problems.